# Al tener un error de conexión a MySQL, ¿puedo hacer que espere 1 segundo y reintente?

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

Buenas, quisiera saber si es posible tratar de reconectarse a la base de datos cuando ocurre un error.

El tema es que tengo un error 1040 *too many connection* recurrente. He visto que esto se puede solucionar aumentando la variable `max_connection`, pero me preguntaba si se podrían realizar varios intentos, supongamos 5 para tratar de reconectarse antes de lanzar ese error.

Sería algo así:

```
<?
php $con = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "", "bd"); 
<----error--->
if($con->connect_errno) {
    //espera 1 seg
    //trata de reconectarse
}
else{
    die("Error: " . $con->connect_errno . "---" . $con->connect_error);
}
return $con;
?>
```

haciendo uso de un for o un while.

¿es posible realizar esto?

---

Además, les dejo el script donde realizo la conexión (que utilizo para traer las características de los productos, que son como unos 50 productos cada uno), en caso de que esta sea la fuente del error por "demasiadas conexiones".

```
<?php
        include"con.php";
       mysqli_query($con,"SET NAMES 'utf8'");
        $result=mysqli_query($con,"select * from bio, carac where
idprod=5");
while($data=mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
....
}
$con->close();
?>
```

Comment: la respuesta corta es si... pero deberas tener cuidado de no caer en un bucle infinito...

Comment: ¿Como podria hacerlo? @gbianchi o ¿donde podria conseguir informacion acerca de eso? ya que no tengo idea de como realizarlo

Comment: ¿Qué error te está dando? ¿Y por qué crees que esperar 1 segundo lo va a solucionar?

Comment: @Mariano tengo un error 1040 too many connection he visto que esto se puede solucionar aumentando la variable max_connection, pero me preguntaba si se podria realizar varios intentos supongamos 5 para tratar de reconectarse antes de lanzar ese error

Comment: @Xiaron para empezar, buscaría si no estás dejando conexiones abiertas que puedas cerrar (el problema de raíz!!!). Luego, agregaría esa información en la pregunta (-es más que relevante!), e intentaría buscar que reintente sólo si se da ese error.

Comment: @Mariano aqui te dejo el codigo que utilizo para consultar no se si es que no estoy cerrando la conexion bien o si es por algun otro motivo por eso andaba buscando una solucion como esa de reintentar conectarse esperando x tiempo

Comment: @Xiaron por casualidad, ¿no estarás usando variables con diferente nombre para la conexión y para cerrarla (`$con` versus `$conexion`).

Comment: @Mariano disculpa no me habia dado cuenta de eso, pero si las variables tienen el mismo nombre, ya lo he editado para evitar esa confusion

Comment: Tambien revisa que tu conexión esta hecho en `estilo orientado a objetos` y tu sentencia (query) en `estilo por procedimientos`.

Comment: _El tema es que tengo un error 1040 too many connection recurrente. He visto que esto se puede solucionar aumentando la variable max_connection_ Pero yo me pregunto si no es mejor solucionarlo **optimizando tu código**, revisando por ejemplo a qué se debe que haya tantas conexiones recurrentes... ¿quizá dejas conexiones abiertas innecesariamente? ¿quizá sea mejor usar una conexión persistente? Da la impresión de que implementar un código que haga esperar para intentar conectarse de nuevo, suena a una solución que será a la corta o a la larga, mediocre. Lo digo con todo respeto. Saludos.

Comment: @A.Cedano si busco esta solucion para corto plazo y he revisado mi codigo y he cerrado todas las conexiones despues de terminar con ellas, el numero de visitas que recibe la pagina es grande y el maximo de conexiones que permite es de 101 quiero aumentar el nro de conexiones pero no he podido comunicarme con mi proveedor de hosting

Comment: Yo tengo una página con conexiones persistentes usando PDO y hasta ahora no tengo ningún problema. No es una página super famosa, pero recibe varios miles de visitas al día y casi todas las url acceden a la BD usando dicha conexión persistente.

Answer (score 0):

Creo que lo que estás buscando es la función de PHP [sleep](http://php.net/manual/es/function.sleep.php).

Dormir durante 10 segundos

```
if($con->connect_errno) {
    sleep(10);
}
```

Comment: en realidad @Mariano esta dentro de un if.. mas que parar de procesar y que sea un espanto para el usuario, no pasaria mas nada.. Igual no creo que sea la solucion que necesita OP...